# How to call Google APIs using SailsJS

Tags: node.js, google-api, sails.js

I would like calculator distance between 2 coordinates using GMap API.
I'm looking for anyway to catch return data from URL

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco&key={{myKey}}
```

I tried to searching but no any thing I purpose.
Please help me or give me keywords. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the super awesome [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package

**From it's documentation:**

Request is designed to be the simplest way possible to make http calls. It supports HTTPS and follows redirects by default.

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage. 
  }
})
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Google's own API documentation should contain everything you need:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix

First geocode your origin and destination from cities (or whatever) to LatLng objects:

> Geocoding is the process of converting addresses (like "1600
>   Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates
>   (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739), which you can use
>   to place markers on a map, or position the map.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Using the LatLng objects you get in response, call Distance Matrix Service.

Comment: Tks for your answer, but I knew how to call GMap API (by using PHP & Javascript). I am newbie on Sails. I'm looking for anything in Sails like CURL in PHP)